# NSOperation not removing from NSOperationQueue after finished taks?

Tags: ios, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

hi i am using Xcode 5+ and iOS 7+ , and implementing NSOperationQueue. i create a subclass of NSOpeartion and say i have 50 + operation added to NSOperationQueue. isExecuting and isFinished is overridden in NSOperation`s start method -

```
-(void)start{

   // soeme code is here 

   [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
  _isExecuting = YES;
  [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];

  [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
  _ isFinished = NO;
  [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
}
```

and after completion task i write this code

```
 [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
  _isExecuting = NO;
  [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];

  [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
  _ isFinished = YES;
  [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
```

MaxConcurrentOperationCount is 2. But after completion of 2 operation next (3rd operation) doesn't get execute main method. please give me some clarification about when this issue comes.

Thanks

Comment: Is the code above for your project? You are not setting _isFinished ...

Comment: thanks, it was my mistake and i have edited the above code.

Answer (score 3):

Upon startup, you should set `isExecuting` to `YES` but you should not set `isFinished` at all, especially not to `YES`.

When your async operation is done, you need to set `isExecuting` to `NO`, not `YES`, and you need to set `isFinished` to `YES` but you are setting `isExecuting` a 2nd time.

Comment: thanks, now after updating code in main of NSOperation i set isExecuting = NO, isFinished = NO, and when operation is done i set isExecuting = NO, isFinished = YES. so please tell what would be the issue here ,

Comment: You need to set `isExecuting` to `YES` at the start of the operation.